# GitHub API - How do I find out if a file is actually a symlink?

Tags: rest, github, github-api

When querying a symlink via the GitHub API, I get different results if the symlink points to a file as opposed to a directory. The latter is more well behaved in that it returns `"type": "symlink"` as part of its JSON, whereas the former returns `"type": "file"`. Example [file symlink](https://api.github.com/repos/aknuds1/littlebits-arduino/contents/muzhack/files/littleBitsMidiNotes.ino), example [directory symlink](https://api.github.com/repos/aknuds1/Littlebits-Arduino/contents/muzhack/files/adapter-board-files).

It's very confusing when a symlink advertises itself as a file, *as GET-ing its download URL will just get you the target of the symlink and not the file contents*.

How do I tell if a file is actually a symlink, as opposed to a real file?

Also, is the behaviour of returning type "file" for file symlinks a downright bug? It just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is unfortunately "you don't". There is no way (with the API in its current state) to differentiate between a file request and a symlink. From [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#response-if-content-is-a-symlink):

> If the requested :path points to a symlink, and the symlink's target is a normal file in the repository, then the API responds with the content of the file [...]
>
> Otherwise, the API responds with an object describing the symlink itself:

I raised this with GitHub support and they confirmed there's no way to do this. They offered to raise it as a request with the internal teams, but I would imagine it's unlikely to get picked up.

One work around (that isn't suitable in all scenarios) is to request the file via https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ which will return either the file contents if it's a real file, or just the file path if it's a symlink.

Answer (score 0):

A symlink in Git doesn't care whether the target is a file or a directory.  (Or even if the target exists.)

The API is *not* returning "file" for symlink  The file in question is *not* a symbolic link.  It's a regular file.  After cloning your repository:

```
% ls -Flas muzhack/files/littleBitsMidiNotes.ino
4 -rw-r--r--  1 user  group  3247 Jun  7 12:00 muzhack/files/littleBitsMidiNotes.ino

% git ls-files --stage muzhack/files/littleBitsMidiNotes.ino
100644 08918243048ae4a4f57e69a34776e9a0bd1ec7af 0   muzhack/files/littleBitsMidiNotes.ino
```

A mode of `100644` (that first field returned by `ls-files`) indicates that this is a regular file.  In contrast, the entry that GitHub is reporting as a symlink is, in fact, a symbolic link:

```
% ls -Flas muzhack/files/adapter-board-files 
4 lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group  25 Jun  7 12:00 muzhack/files/adapter-board-files@ -> ../../adapter-board-files

% git ls-files --stage muzhack/files/adapter-board-files
120000 ef17a5e7b4bef4e51f19dc6b4c360c95cbb223c8 0   muzhack/files/adapter-board-files
```

So the GitHub API appears to be reporting this information correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I made the symlink into a normal file temporarily to work around the bug. Going to change it back into a symlink soon :)

Comment: OK, file made back into symlink. Go.

Comment: If you open https://github.com/aknuds1/Littlebits-Arduino/blob/master/muzhack/files/littleBitsMidiNotes.ino, you should see that it is reported as a symlink by GitHub.

Comment: Aha, thanks for the clarification.  Obviously I'm quite mistaken then, as https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/ documents this as the intended behavior here...

Comment: Strange. The thing is the symlink claims to be a file, but if you GET the `download_url`, you'll only receive the path the symlink points to and not the file's actual contents. I.e., it claims to be a file, but isn't. Quite puzzling really and not something I can work with :/